# Python create an area screenshot

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, automated-tests

Is it possible in python to create an area screenshot like this example ?

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANUti.png)

```
import pyautogui

def capture_current_scene(name_screenshot, i):
    im1= pyautogui.screenshot()
    im1.save(name_screenshot+'_'+str(i))


def capture_area_scene():
    currentMouseX1, currentMouseY1 = pyautogui.position()

    # click one ==> initialize a rectangle form

    currentMouseX2, currentMouseY2 = pyautogui.position()

    # click two ==> end the rectangle form
    # you created an area screenshot
```

Comment: Does the code you posted not work? If so what is the issue?

Comment: I think it is clear, the code works for the whole screen, the OP wants to be able to draw a rectangle and get the screen from there.

Comment: It's unclear what the position of the mouse has to do with this. Can you explain it better please? You are doing automated testing? Surely you aren't moving the mouse yourself?

Comment: @MarkSetchell What I want to do it's to take screenshot of my desktop for example and then i want to choose an area in this screenshot. Yes i move by myself the mouse to choose wich area i want to take and finally save this area as a new screenshot.

Comment: Where's the main program that calls these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you can do this. First you display the screenshot of the full image (resized if necessary).  A MouseCallback is created that stores the x/y position of the mouse when pressed, draws a rectangle on the image when dragging pressed, and upon mouse release creates a subimage.

Result:
[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 

img = cv2.imread("screenshot.jpg", 1)
click1 = False
point1 = (0,0)

def click(event,x,y,flags, params):
        global click1, point1
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
                # if mousedown, store the x,y position of the mous
                click1 = True
                point1 = (x,y)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE and click1:
                # when dragging pressed, draw rectangle in image
                img_copy = img.copy()
                cv2.rectangle(img_copy, point1, (x,y), (0,0,255),2)
                cv2.imshow("Image", img_copy)
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
                # on mouseUp, create subimage
                click1 = False
                sub_img = img[point1[1]:y,point1[0]:x]
                cv2.imshow("subimg", sub_img)

cv2.namedWindow("Image")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Image", click)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's exatly what I wanted !